# How to add an icon on the right side of Bootstrap input?

Tags: html, css

I have a snippet code:

```html
<div class="container" style="margin: 50px">
  <div class="form-group">
    <span class="fa fa-search form-control-icon"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div> 
</div>
```

```css
.form-group .form-control {
    padding-left: 2.375rem;
}

.form-group .form-control-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 2.375rem;
    height: 2.375rem;
    line-height: 2.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

[image]

How to change the current CSS to have the icon on the right side?

Seems `padding-right: 2.375rem;` is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using position absolute, you need to define the parent element as position:relative.

Also you need to define the right and top position for it to fix.

```
.form-group .form-control {
    padding-left: 2.375rem;
}
.form-group{
  position:relative;
}
.form-group .form-control-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 2.375rem;
    height: 2.375rem;
    line-height: 2.375rem;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #aaa;
    right:0;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Working jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/47up2sax/

Comment: With `padding-right: 2.375rem;` not `left`, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `right` property with the appropriate value to move it to the right. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pda7c8kx/1/) (I used 'x' as for some reason the icon was not loading in the fiddle).